# Performance effect using $this -> render(); while developing a layout?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

A lot of time, it becomes necessary to separate some section commonly used like banner, footer to a separate file and later on include this parts as `$this -> render('banner.phtml')`.

When this is used extensively, how costly does it become performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it has some sort of bad effect on performace. I am working on very large product and I have extensively used `$this->render()` in my project for handling various things. If you are not having a common layout then you have to rely on this function. But if you are having a common layout throughout the project, then there is no need of this. So don't worry on using the `render` function.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of `Zend_View_Abstract` it should be fine do have multiple calls. `render()` essentially does:

- Look up the script. One operation for each scriptpatch you have.
- Run the file, encapsuled by `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. Should not cause any performance issues.
- Run each filter on the output.

Unless you don't have hundreds of scriptpaths' or filteres added, performance should be ok. Note however that especially nested `render()` calls require more memory (due to possibly stacked output-buffers).

But of course you want to cache as much as possible anyway - making most of the `render()`-calls run only once ;).